# Codeigniter not loading CI super object

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am trying to write a hook for my `Codeigniter` application.

I'm trying to catch a `session` in my `hook`.

Here is my code to load the hook:

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
  'function' => 'getNav',
  'filename' => 'LoadNav.php',
  'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

And here is the code I'm trying to load in the hook:

```
function getNav()
{
     $CI =& get_instance();
     $level = $CI->session->userdata('level');
}
```

It keeps throwing an error which is the following:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: hooks/LoadNav.php
Line Number: 7
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong? It seems like the get_instance method is not functioning right?

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Alain

Comment: Try var_dumping the `$CI` variable

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Something like `$CI =& get_instance();` looks like PHP4 code to me

Comment: @afuzzyllama: How does that look like "PHP4 code"? It assigns a variable by reference to the output of `get_instance()` (a function). What is "PHP4" about that?

Comment: My mistake, I though it was something along the lines of this, but it isn't... http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot access the `$CI` instance in a `pre_controller` hook - as per the docs:

> **pre_controller hook** Called immediately prior to any of your controllers being called. All base classes, routing, and security checks have been done..

It is the CI `Controller`which allows access to `get_instance()`. Until a controller is instantiated, there is nothing to *get*.

Try `post_controller_constructor` instead and see if that gets you the desired results.

In `system/Core/Controller.php`:

```
class CI_Controller {

// <snip>

    public static function &get_instance()
    {
        return self::$instance;
    }

}
    // END Controller class
```

Comment: I figured it out. Then came back and saw this. Perfect answer! Thank you!